# QStringList file directory and filename

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have been trying to get a list of all the file names of some images in a directory into a QStringList, the only problem is that I want the name of the directories to also be included in the resulting string.  For example, my list only consists of various image names such as "image_x.jpg" but I want the directories included too, such as "../../images/image_x.jpg". I have been trying different methods for the past few hours and have looked at the Qt docs and I am still stuck. Thanks in advance.

```
QDir dir ("../../images/");
dir.setSorting(QDir::Name);
QStringList list = dir.entryList(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::Dirs);

for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    qDebug() << "Filename " + QString::number(i) + " = " + list.at(i);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the folder path you give to `QDir` with the file names?

Comment: I tried to concatenate and also various methods of both QStringList and QList. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What was the problem? `list[i] = "../../images/" + list[i]` should work

Comment: Thanks. I was trying list.at(i) = "../../images/" + list.at(i) for some reason. Time to go to bed I think :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QDir::entryInfoList` and `QFileInfo::filePath`:

```
QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::AllEntries);
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    qDebug() << "Filename " + QString::number(i) + " = " + list.at(i).filePath();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `QDir::filePath`:

```
QStringList list = dir.entryList(QDir::AllEntries);
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    qDebug() << "Filename " << i << " = " << dir.filePath(list.at(i));
}
```

Note that `QDir::AllEntries` already includes `QDir::Dirs`, so there is no point in adding it again.

This approach has advantage against manually adding dir path to file path: Qt will correctly process cases when path ends or not ends with slash, and possibly other unforeseen cases.